# Removing items From Array Is Adding Blank Item instead

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to remove the items in an array that have been check marked. the function I am using is adding one blank value to the instead of removing the ones that I check mark,

How can I fix this function to work as I desire?

```
   $('#clearChecked').click(function() {
  var newArray = [];
  $('.check').each( function (n, obj) {
      if (!$(obj).is(':checked')) {
          $('#form')[0].reset();
          var keyWords = $('#keyWords').html();
          newArray.push(keyWords);
          localStorage.setItem('keyWords', JSON.stringify(newArray));
          loadKeyWords();
          return false;
      }
  });
});
```

html

```
<input class="check" name="check" type="checkbox"></li>
```

Comment: I do not see how you remove your item.

Comment: `#keyWords` can not be multiple elements, every element should have a unique `id`, you should iterate over a class instead.

Comment: I updated to class check and added the input for you to see. When I changed this the button continues to add a blank value to the array

Comment: @NichoDiaz provide full html, please

Comment: You can try recreating the array with only the values you want to keep then doing a deep copy to the original variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
$('#clearChecked').click(function() {
  currentArray = [];
  $('.check').each(function() {
    var $curr = $(this);
    if (!$curr.is(':checked')) {
      var value = $curr.parent().text();
      currentArray.push(value);
      localStorage.setItem('keyWords', JSON.stringify(currentArray));
      loadKeyWords();
    } else {
      $curr.parent().remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Basically I am creating a new array with the kayWords that have not been check marked and pushing them back to localStorage.